# How to handle Action's form data that is not coming from JSP in Struts 2?

Tags: java, forms, struts2, struts-action

I have a form in search.jsp

```
<s:form name="employeeSearchForm" action="searchAction" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="id" label="Employee ID"/>
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Employee Name"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

In struts.xml

```
<package name="example" namespace="/" extends="default">

    <action name="searchAction" class="example.SearchAction">
        <result>/example/search.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Then the SearchAction class

```
public class SearchAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        if ("".equals(id.trim())) {    //#1

        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

See the #1 line code, if I clicked submit button from the Form in search.jsp, the **id** field will not be null, but if I open `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapps/searchAction.action` directly, **id** field will be null.

In this case, I can use field check in SearchAction.exeucte(), e.g. **if (id != null)** , but I doubt if it's the most elegant way.

Anyone can suggest better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private String id="";`  \quick fix.

But app shouldn't allow the user hitting the action directly user should be authenticated and/or authorized before.

Comment: Thanks, it works. How to authenticate user or prevent user hitting action directly? I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

In web environment it is usually hard to tell whether user provided input or not (empty vs null). In your case you can validate values using Struts2 validation http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html.